# What does * (star) or other kinds mean in an instance list of haddock

Tags: haskell, haddock, type-kinds, polykinds

Browsing the haddocks of various packages I often come along instance documentations that look like this ([Control.Category](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html)):

```
Category k (Coercion k)
Category * (->)
```

or this ([Control.Monad.Trans.Identity](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Identity.html)):

```
MonadTrans (IdentityT *)
```

What exactly here does the kind signature mean? It doesn't show up in the source, but I have already noticed that it seems to occur in modules that use the *PolyKinds* extension. I suspect it is probably like a TypeApplication but with a kind. So that e.g. the last example means that `IdentityT` is a monad transformer if it's first argument has kind `*`.

So my questions are:

- Is my interpretation correct and what exactly does the kind signature refer to?
- In the first `Category` instance, how am I supposed to know that `k` is a kind and not a type? Or do I just have to know the arity of `Category`?
- What is the source code analog to this syntax?

I am not asking for an explanation of kinds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[To quote Richard Eisenberg’s recent post on the haskell-cafe mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-January/125985.html):

> Haddock struggles sometimes to render types with `-XPolyKinds` enabled. The problem is that GHC generally does not require kind arguments to be written and it does not print them out (unless you say `-fprint-explicit-kinds`). But Haddock, I believe, prints out kinds whenever `-XPolyKinds` is on. So the two different definitions are really the same: it's just that one module has `-XPolyKinds` and the other doesn't.
>
> The `*` is the kind of ordinary types. So `Int` has kind `*` (we write `Int :: *`) while `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`. `Typeable` actually has kind `forall k. k -> Constraint`, meaning that it's polykinded. In the first snippet below, the `*` argument to `Typeable` instantiates `k` with `*`, because type variable a has kind `*`.

So yes, as you guessed, it has to do with `PolyKinds`. Haddock renders these poly-kinded types with a sort of “explicit kind application”. It just so happens that `Category` is poly-kinded, having the kind `forall k. (k -> k -> *) -> Constraint`, so Haddock renders the kind application alongside each instance.

In my opinion, this is a bug or misfeature of Haddock, since there is no equivalent source code analog as far as I know. It is confusing, and I don’t know of a better way to understand it than to recognize the way it usually manifests and visually infer what’s going on from the context.

Comment: Agreed, I also consider this a bug. Maybe using `Category @k (Coercion k)` would be a better notation.

Comment: There are cases where it needs to specify the kind of type variables that aren't present in the type.  That combination makes it really hard to find a sane way to document.